# Angular2 reases CORS error with Payara Basic auth

Tags: angular, cors, payara

I am trying to sign into my rest API using Basic authentication on my Payara server the Java EE application. But when I try to make a request. I receive an unauthorized and CORS header error.

The code to make the request.

```
var data = null;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/twitter/api/tweet/get?id=7");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
xhr.setRequestHeader("postman-token", "d2883762-63dc-3158-ea76-21ff13182cee");

xhr.send(data);
```

The error.
[image: error message]

I added this code to apply the right headers but they do not seem to work.

```
@Provider
public class NewCrossOriginResourceSharingFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext response) {
        response.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        response.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your API is not enabled to allow OPTIONS http method. In a CORS scenario there is a pre-flight request made with http method as OPTIONS before the actual call. To support this, your API should allow both OPTIONS and GET http methods.